# Internet Explorer adds height- and width-attributes to a newly appended image automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I append a newly created image after it has been loaded to the DOM:

```
var i = $('<img/>');
i[0].src = 'http://placehold.it/700x300';
i.attr('alt', '');
i.on('load', function() {
    $('body').append(i);            
});
```

---

I have set a fixed height for the images in CSS:

```
img {
    height: 150px;
}
```

---

Unfortunately the Internet Explorer adds the `width`- and `height`-attributes to the image so it gets heavily distorted. How can I prevent this? Do I have to manually remove the attributes after I append the element?

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BKfNx/)

Comment: IE doesn't add tags to the markup, something else is doing it.

Comment: just add width as well !! http://jsfiddle.net/aEaEN/

Comment: @TravisO If you inspect the fiddle you see, that there are the attributes set in IE.

Comment: @codeiz Yes, width set to auto did the trick. I was sure I tested it, but I must missed it somehow. I can't set a fixed width, as the width is unknown.

Comment: IE does not add attributes, but it scales the image so that width : height ratio is not preserved.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela But why is the first image in the fiddle that is included directly into the DOM not distorted?

Comment: It seems that it’s the jQuery code somehow. It does not happen if you create an `img` element just with `document.createElement` and append it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
img {
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tested this before asking. Works fine. :D Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I was just waiting for the timer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can either add !important to your css, or remove the width and height attrs.

```
img {
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

or

```
i.height('').width('');
```