# IE 11 automatically adds a width/height attribute to image object

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Today I've ended up troubleshooting an IE 11 problem on our website that was causing some images to be incorrectly displayed.

So running this under IE 11:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://placehold.it/900x450";
document.body.appendChild(img);

var img2 = document.createElement('img');
img2.src = "http://placehold.it/900x450";
document.body.appendChild(img2);
```

Seems to yield two different outputs. The image created by instantiating the image object has the width/height attributes defined, the image created through the document.createElement function does not.

Here's what I'm seeing [(JSFiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/4zuw3qvv/):

[image: jsfiddle exposing the problem]

I was also able to replicate the issue by creating a simple HTML page (to be absolutely sure that isn't some kind of magic being done by JSFiddle):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var img = new Image();
      var img2 = document.createElement('img');

      img.src = "http://placehold.it/900x450";
      document.body.appendChild(img);

      img2.src = "http://placehold.it/900x450";
      document.body.appendChild(img2);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally here's the IE version I'm running:

[image: internet explorer version]

I'd really appreciate if someone took a bit of their time to explain me if this is an expected behavior and if so, why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer adds height- and width-attributes to a newly appended image automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922942/internet-explorer-adds-height-and-width-attributes-to-a-newly-appended-image-au)