# Javascript images behave differently in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

In IE 11 the image is scaled incorrectly because it seems like IE sets the width and height attributes of a dynamically created image whereas Firefox/Chrome don't.

```js
$(function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "http://placehold.it/350x1200";
    $("div").append($(image));
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

I tried setting the dimensions to undefined or 0 after/before setting the src but then the image doesn't render.

How can I achieve cross-browser consistency without extra checks for IE? Is there a way of removing the width/height attributes at the right time so that it works for all browsers regardless of whether the image is cached or not? Also I might not know the image dimensions beforehand.

**Note**: The problem doesn't show in the SO snippet but on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmyhcepb/5/) and with local html files.

**Edit:** Here's what the image looks like in Firefox/Chrome:

[image] [image]

This is in IE11:

[image] [image]

Comment: the max-width style rule uses absolute units, not relative values. To size a child inline block element to its parent block element use style="width:100%"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922942/internet-explorer-adds-height-and-width-attributes-to-a-newly-appended-image-au

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because it seems like IE sets the width and height attributes of a dynamically created image

Well, I would not phrase it that way. I would rather say, trying to “make” a JS `Image` element into append-able HTML code by using `$(image)` seems to have this unexpected result here - but that code looks “weird” to me to begin with.

Once you replace that with a simple

```
$("div").append('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x1200">');
```

IE 11 shows the image the same as the other browsers.

Comment: A JS image should be a `HTMLImageElement` like any other (but not in IE it seems). I'm using the Image constructor because the resulting image object makes it easy to set `onload` before setting `src` but it should also be possible with your solution.

Comment: I think when you are passing the HTMLImageElement to $(), it is converted to a string, so its implicit toString conversion method is called. And I am not sure if that is specified anywhere - so IE and the other browsers might just disagree here on whether including width and height attributes in the resulting HTML string makes sense or not. // But you are correct, this should not stop you from still using `new Image()` beforehand to be able to attach a load handler; you can simply combine both.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

to

```
img{width:100%}
```

to stop the child element overflowing or resizing the parent div's height, add an overflow:hidden; rule to the div. Otherwise the image will be rendered with a different aspect ratio to its natural values and will look weird.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to limit the height. Also the aspect ratio is correct in Firefox/Chrome (29x100). Only in IE it becomes a 100x100 square.